# What does this notation mean in Linear Algebra when talking about subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I will get straight to the point. What does this notation mean when talking about subspaces in linear algebra?

$S = \{ (x_1, x_2) \mid  x_2 = 2x_1 \}$

I see this all the time. Is it subspace notation?

Comment: It's the same as saying $S=\{(x_1,2x_1\}$. If $x_1$ is taken to be any real number, this defines a line (and actually, this is the same as saying $y=2x$ (taking $x_1=x, x_2=y$)!).

Answer (score 4):

This is [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). It should be read

> "$S$ is the set of all pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $x_2 = 2x_1$."

This is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and now you can ask whether or not it's a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for the clearing up some of my ambiguities :)

Comment: @plee Is there anything else you still don't understand? Feel free to tell us about it so we can clarify everything for you.